# preg_match valid file name from a to z and special character

Tags: php, preg-match

I want allow this file name type:

A-Z letters
a-z letters
1-x numbers
Special character: "(" ")" "-"

If you can help me with preg_match rules I was tried  but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$filename = "A-(";
if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9-\(\)]+$/", $filename)) {
    echo "matched";
}
```